# Uninstalling SQL Server instance, I lost my user database

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

IT admin has uninstalled the test SQL Server instance. It had a huge real time test data.
I want to know if

1. Uninstalling an instance deletes the database?
2. Is there way to recover the lost database?

Comment: Not really a coding question so I've suggested a move but, as scottm says, if you still have the .mdf... Otherwise you could contact the IT admin about your organisation's extensive and effective backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. As long as the `.mdf` file is still on the disk, you can attach it to a new instance.

Comment: For how long .mdf files stays in the folder??

Comment: Until you delete them. I think there is an option when unistalling an instance to delete all attached databases as well, so it depends if that was checked or not. Otherwise, they stay there until you delete them. Usually somewhere around `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

If the .mdf files are still out there, you should be able to just reattach to the live instance.